# Gmaps js stopped working "map.setCenter is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I implemented a map on my homepage, it's shown when the user searches for a city, the map is centered on that city and markers with shops are added to it. It was working until a while ago, then it stopped working suddenly, giving me the following errors:

```
Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript library https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.
GMaps @ gmaps.js:187

Uncaught TypeError: map.setCenter is not a function
    at callback (mapa.js:20)
    at gmaps.js:2284
    at maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/geocoder.js:5
    at maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/geocoder.js:3
    at US (maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/geocoder.js:2)
    at Km.<anonymous> (maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/geocoder.js:3)
    at maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/common.js:49
    at Xm.f (maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/common.js:26)
    at Km.Ym (maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/common.js:49)
    at Object.c [as _geggq6] (maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/1/intl/pt_br/common.js:43)
```

The code is to big to put in the question text, so here is a fiddle with the html section of the map and js file:

https://jsfiddle.net/t7uq3cbL/

I tried a lot of solutions in similar questions, but none seemed to work. There is no particular condition for this error to happen, it simply occurs when it feels like it.

Comment: this might help: `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat, results[0].geometry.location.lng);

                    map.setCenter(latlng);`

Comment: Oh, and you'll want to set-up and api-key.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same error. I have set an API key too. I thought it might be exceeding the daily requisitions limit, but the site hasn't even half the 25k requisitions limit a day.

Comment: & you've tried visiting the api-url manually? I've seen the often where lat/lng are strings, not numbers. But if google-maps is working is loading fine, than I'm not sure.

Comment: Tried it now, accessed with no problems.